# Redefine \includegraphics* (starred version)

Tags: includegraphics, starred-version

I have this code:

```latex
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\colorbox{white}{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}}
```

How can I make it work with the starred version of `\includegraphics`?

I get this error if `\includegraphics*` is used in the file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `*' not found.
```

Comment: you could use NewDocumentCommand rather than newcommand and define a * form of your new command that uses the * form of the original, although I'm surprised you need the star form at all, it doesn't do anything very useful in `graphicx` it was only really for `graphics`, which essentially no one uses these days

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm a copy editor and I just found `\includegraphics*` in a paper I'm editing. I didn't even know of the `\includegraphics`'s starred version. I redefine temporarily '\includegraphics` to better check the blank margins of the figure (I use also a colored background for the page).

Comment: I just found, not tried (sorry). May be an old-style author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shown would also disable the second optional argument of `\includegraphics`

The second optional and the `*` form are both really for the `graphics` package interface which is really not used much so one possibility would be to ignore this aspect. (The star form just adds `clip` to the supplied keys, so it is more natural to use `\includegraphics[clip]` than `\includegraphics*` when using `graphicx`.)

However you can support all the argument parsing by hooking in the box after the arguments are parsed

```
\makeatletter
\let\old@Ginclude@graphics\Ginclude@graphics
\def\Ginclude@graphics#1{\colorbox{white}{\old@Ginclude@graphics{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I get: Runaway definition?
#1->\colorbox {white}{\old@Ginclude@graphics {#1}} \makeatother \par \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \Ginclude@graphics.

Comment: Looks like there is a `}` missing at the end of the `\def` line?

Comment: @henryflower fixed thanks (if the OP had provided a test document I would have tested the answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry!